# Which error log does testing.T.Logf() records the text?

Tags: go

For the below code:

```
package tests

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestLog(t *testing.T) {
    t.Logf("\t%s", "\u2713")
    fmt.Printf("\t%s", "\u2713")
}
```

---

Documentation says: "`Logf` formats its arguments according to the format, analogous to `Printf`, and records the text in the error log."

After running the command:

```
$ go test github.com/myhub/codesamples/tests
ok      github.com/myhub/codesamples/tests    (cached)
$
```

I could not see the output

---

Which error log does `t.Logf()` records the text?

Comment: `go help test` for documentation. Please read it.

Answer (score 4):

#### Short answer

For  tests, the text will be printed only if the test fails or the `-test.v` flag is set. For benchmarks, the text is always printed to avoid having performance depend on the value of the -test.v flag.

#### How to see the log

1. test with -test.v flag set

```
$ go test -v github.com/myhub/codesamples/tests
```

2. failing tests show the log irrespective of whether the flag was set or not

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestLog(t *testing.T) {
    t.Logf("log statement \t%s", "\u2713")
    t.Errorf("dummy error log ")
}
```